# Integrate Microsoft WindowsAzure Storage Blob in Codeigniter4

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure-blob-storage, codeigniter-4

Now,I am working Codeigniter 4 PHP framework. And, i added the Microsoft (Microsoft windows Azure storage)  folder into Codeigniter/ThirdParty.

Now, i call the library file
Showing Below error.
Class 'App\Libraries\Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob' not found

library file code:

```
namespace App\Libraries;
require_once APPPATH.'/ThirdParty/Microsoft/WindowsAzure/Storage/Blob.php';
use Microsoft\WindowsAzure\Storage\blob;
new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob('blob.core.windows.net', $account, $key);
```

Is there any idea?
Thanks

Comment: You mean you copied the folder to Codeigniter vendors directory? If so you can't use the APP path,since APP points to the app directory in the root folder of your project.

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/microsoft/windowsazure

Comment: Using above package makes more snse rather than copying the packages and using require_once.